# What can be the reason of bad reducer distribution across the nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In Hadoop MR job `mapreduce.job.reduces` is set equal to number of nodes in cluster (~50).

However, in application UI I see that some nodes got 2-3 reducer tasks and some have 0.

I'd like to have a single reducer for each node. There is no partitioner provided for a job. I expected default hash partitioner to distribute keys evenly across the machines. The key is just a string representing URL, I'm sure there's nothing wrong with key hash code. So what can be the problem?

My guess is that problem is related to YARN resource management but I'm not sure.